# Google Sheet: Is it a good practice to make a whole column as a named range?

Tags: performance, google-sheets

Columns often represent fields, so it is quite logical to make a column a named range. Also, it is often unknown how many rows there will be （for example, a 'order_id' column in sheet 'Orders'）, so it is safe and intuitive to just make a column as a named range instead of name a range with certain rows.

But I'm wondering if this is going to cause performance issue. I have a spreadsheet with around 10 sheets. And I named most of the columns. Lately there has been complaint from my colleague that the sheet is slow to open. I know that's probably because there are lots of datas and formulas in it, but could named range(column) also be part of the issue?

Comment: It's likely that this is causing slowness. Why is it important to have them all as names ranges? What are you doing with them that a simple `A1:A` won't suffice?

Comment: Other people could move the column around. Another benefit is I can just refer the ranges' names in app script without writing their sheets' names.

Comment: I mean to directly answer your question, no, it's not good practice to do this but it can be useful. Sheet slowness mostly comes from size and number of cells, but named ranges can also contribute to this. I would do a test - create a blank sheet and create a lot of named ranges with columns and then see how much the sheet slows compared to just a sheet with many cells.